# Idris : Is it possible to rewrite all functions using "with" to use "case" instead of "with" ? If not, could you give a counter example?

Tags: idris

In Idris, is it possible to rewrite all functions using "[with](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/views.html)" to use "case" instead of "with" ?

If not, could you give a counter example ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not possible. When you pattern match with `with`, the types in the context are updated with information extracted from the matched constructor. `case` doesn't cause such updating.

As an example, the following works with `with` but not with `case`:

```
import Data.So

-- here (n == 10) in the goal type is rewritten to True or False
-- after the match
maybeTen : (n : Nat) -> Maybe (So (n == 10))
maybeTen n with (n == 10)
  maybeTen n | False = Nothing
  maybeTen n | True  = Just Oh

-- Here the context knows nothing about the result of (n == 10)
-- after the "case" match, so we can't fill in the rhs
maybeTen' : (n : Nat) -> Maybe (So (n == 10))
maybeTen' n = case (n == 10) of
  True  => ?a 
  False => ?b
```

Comment: So basically `with` is a kind of `case` that has a "stronger" connection to the type-level than simple `case` has. Very loosely speaking.

Comment: IIRC `with` desugars to a new top-level definition that has the extra arguments compared to the parent function, and it's fundamentally the function definitions that enforce/update all the type dependencies in the argument patterns.

Comment: So this suggests that it is not possible to have multiple `with`-s. Is that correct? For example n==10 and n==9 at the same time, would that make sense ?

Comment: You can use any number of `with`-s (but one at a time in Idris, in Agda we can do any number of introductions with a single `with`, which is convenient). See [example](http://lpaste.net/153319). It's also not an issue that `n == 10` and `n == 9` can't be both true;  in that case you can derive a contradiction, i. e. [`Void`](http://www.idris-lang.org/docs/current/base_doc/docs/[builtins].html#Void), which is our way of telling Idris that a case branch is unreachable.