# Why does this 'with' block spoil the totality of this function?

Tags: idris, termination, totality

I'm trying to compute parity together with the floor of the half, over natural numbers:

```
data IsEven : Nat -> Nat -> Type where
    Times2 : (n : Nat) -> IsEven (n + n) n

data IsOdd : Nat -> Nat -> Type where
    Times2Plus1 : (n : Nat) -> IsOdd (S (n + n)) n

parity : (n : Nat) -> Either (Exists (IsEven n)) (Exists (IsOdd n))
```

I tried going with the obvious implementation of `parity`:

```
parity Z = Left $ Evidence _ $ Times2 0
parity (S Z) = Right $ Evidence _ $ Times2Plus1 0
parity (S (S n)) with (parity n)
  parity (S (S (k + k))) | Left (Evidence _ (Times2 k)) =
      Left $ rewrite plusSuccRightSucc k k in Evidence _ $ Times2 (S k)
  parity (S (S (S ((k + k))))) | Right (Evidence _ (Times2Plus1 k)) =
      Right $ rewrite plusSuccRightSucc k k in Evidence _ $ Times2Plus1 (S k)
```

This typechecks and works as expected. However, if I try to mark `parity` as `total`, Idris starts complaining:

```
 parity is possibly not total due to: with block in parity
```

The only `with` block I see in `parity` is the one with the recursive call from `parity (S (S n))` to `parity n`, but clearly that is well-founded, since `n` is structurally smaller than `S (S n)`.

How do I convince Idris that `parity` is total?

Comment: I opened [issue #4100](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/4100) on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me, because the following solution based on `case` passes the totality checker:

```
total
parity : (n : Nat) -> Either (Exists (IsEven n)) (Exists (IsOdd n))
parity Z = Left $ Evidence _ $ Times2 0
parity (S Z) = Right $ Evidence _ $ Times2Plus1 0
parity (S (S k)) =
  case (parity k) of
    Left (Evidence k (Times2 k)) =>
      Left $ rewrite plusSuccRightSucc k k in Evidence _ $ Times2 (S k)
    Right (Evidence k (Times2Plus1 k)) =>
      Right $ rewrite plusSuccRightSucc k k in Evidence _ $ Times2Plus1 (S k)
```

Comment: I can confirm this workaround works for my problem in the original question -- but in other situations, a `with` cannot always be rewritten into a `case`, right? I'm thinking of cases where the pattern match refines the types of other arguments.

Comment: Right! Here is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35610366/2747511. We are lucky that we have proofs in the context.

Comment: Hmm, so, does that mean I should try manually unfolding these `with`s and see if that works?

Comment: Nope; that still doesn't pass the totality checker... so I guess I'm at an impasse now.

Comment: Do you mean you have some other bigger example?