# `case` that refines arguments

Tags: pattern-matching, idris, unification

In [this answer on a question about the totality checker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563163/477476), a workaround involving using `case` instead of `with` was recommended.

However, in situations where the result of the match refines the type of other arguments, this transformation is not straightforward to make.

For example, given the following definitions:

```
data IsEven : Nat -> Nat -> Type where
    Times2 : (n : Nat) -> IsEven (n + n) n

data IsOdd : Nat -> Nat -> Type where
    Times2Plus1 : (n : Nat) -> IsOdd (S (n + n)) n

total parity : (n : Nat) -> Either (Exists (IsEven n)) (Exists (IsOdd n))
```

the following definition typechecks, but is not accepted as total:

```
foo1 : Nat -> Nat
foo1 n with (parity n)
  foo1 n@(k + k) | Left (Evidence _ (Times2 k)) = (n * n)
  foo1 n@(S (k + k)) | Right (Evidence _ (Times2Plus1 k)) = (2 * (k * n + k))
```

whereas the following one doesn't typecheck:

```
foo2 : Nat -> Nat
foo2 n = case parity n of
  Left (Evidence k (Times2 k)) => n * n
  Right (Evidence k (Times2Plus1 k)) => (2 * (k * n + k))
```

due to

```
Type mismatch between
      IsEven (k + k) k (Type of Times2 k)
and
      IsEven n k (Expected type)
```

I also tried [expanding the `with` in `foo1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35610366/idris-is-it-possible-to-rewrite-all-functions-using-with-to-use-case-inste#comment58946793_35610859):

```
foo1' : (n : Nat) -> Either (Exists (IsEven n)) (Exists (IsOdd n)) -> Nat
foo1' n@(k + k) (Left (Evidence k (Times2 k))) = (n * n)
foo1' n@(S (k + k)) (Right (Evidence k (Times2Plus1 k))) = 2 * (k * n + k)

foo1 : Nat -> Nat
foo1 n = foo1' n (parity n)
```

but here, `foo1'` is also not accepted as total:

```
 foo1' is not total as there are missing cases
```

Comment: Wow! Please look at `foo2` here: https://pastebin.com/KbS6vT0H :)

Answer (score 1):

One effective workaround I've found for this is to re-bind `n` in each branch, i.e. to write `foo2` as

```
foo2 : Nat -> Nat
foo2 n = case parity n of
  Left (Evidence k (Times2 k)) => let n = k + k in n * n
  Right (Evidence k (Times2Plus1 k)) => let n = S (k + k) in (2 * (k * n + k))
```

Unfortunately, while this works for this simplified problem from my original question, it doesn't work when the types of the various branches differ; for example in

```
total Foo : Nat -> Type
Foo n = case parity n of
    Left (Evidence k (Times2 k)) => ()
    Right (Evidence k (Times2Plus1 k)) => Bool

foo : (n : Nat) -> Foo n
foo n = case parity n of
    Left (Evidence k (Times2 k)) => ()
    Right (Evidence k (Times2Plus1 k)) => True
```

which fails with

```
 Type mismatch between
         () (Type of ())
 and
         case parity (plus k k) of
           Left (Evidence k (Times2 k)) => ()
           Right (Evidence k (Times2Plus1 k)) => Bool (Expected type)
```